# Where to save the PHP file to process the form in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was trying to make a simple chat in WordPress, where I need some information to be processed using PHP. To do this, I have a button in my HTML, and there is a JavaScript function called when someone clicks on the button. Here is the JavaScript:

```
function chatinitial(){
        var user=document.getElementById("chatuser").value;
        jQuery.post("./chat.php",{stage:"initial",user:user},function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

}
```

This seems to be not working. I feel like it has to do with where I save the `chat.php` file at. Right now I have it under my theme's folder, the same directory where the `index.php` file where my HTMLs are written. How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to give `.post()` a valid relative or absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `functions.php` file of your theme to add any WP hooks to parse the data and/or include any other php file needed.

It is not good practice to post to a external php file in wordpress (or CMS in general), so you should post to the url that matches the current application. Then use a hook in wp like `init` to check if post data from the chat have been posted and then parse them or even include the external `chat.php` file

example (`functions.php`):

```
add_action('init', 'parse_chat');

function parse_chat()
{
   if (isset($_POST['chat']))
   {
       // include the chat.php file, make sure the correct path is used
       include './chat.php';
       // .. process
       // optionaly you can also exit here
       // exit;
   } 
}
```